# Javascript Array Object undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

Trying to access an array object to send the data to a view in Cakephp. I keep getting an "uncaught reference error, object undefined" in console. Here's the code:

```
        /* initialize the calendar
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    var arrayOfEvents = [];
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        events: [
            <?php foreach ($users as $user) { foreach ($user['Event'] as $event): ?>
            {
                start: '<?php echo $event['start_date']; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $event['end_date']; ?>',
                title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                allDay: false,
                color: '#077169'
            },
            <?php endforeach; } ?>
        ],
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.end = (date.getTime() + 3600000) / 1000; // default shift length is 1 hour
            copiedEventObject.userId = originalEventObject.userId;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = false;
            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
            // Push events into array
    --->        arrayOfEvents.push(copiedEventObject);
            //todo: the calendar needs to insert events into the event calendar. 
            console.log(arrayOfEvents);
        }
    });
});

function updateSchedule()
{
  --->  var data = "numOfEvents=" +  arrayOfEvents.length;


    // You can get all events out of the array here
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfEvents.length; i++) {
        var event = arrayOfEvents[i];
        data += "&id" + i + "=" + event.id
                + "&start" + i + "=" + event.start
                + "&end" + i + "=" + event.end;
    }

    // Make your ajax post here
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>events/add",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('done!');
        },
        fail: function(response) {
            alert("error");
        }

    });
}
```

The arrayOfEvents is defined when a Scheduler drops a Person onto the calendar. It is transferring all of their information onto the arrayOfEvents object. I have a link for Schedulers to add all of the recently scheduled people to the database through an ajax call. It appears the function is not receiving the arrayOfEvents. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is your code complete? It seems it miss the first part.

Comment: The first part just transfers the data from the users table to the calendar. I'm getting all the data I need into the arrayOfEvents. The console.log is showing it.

Comment: It looks like your arrayOfEvents  is not in the global scope, is it inside some other handler? you can try by taking the line "var arrayOfEvents = [];" just above the function updateSchedule.

Comment: Unrelated: Your code will break in IE. You have a TRAILING COMMA OF DEATH in the `events` array.

Comment: @sdespont That did it. If you want to put in an answer, I'll give you the credit. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `});` before function `updateSchedule` shows us that the variable `arrayOfEventsis` not defined in the same scope. Move `updateSchedule` in the same scope, or the variable `arrayOfEventsis` outisde its current scope.

Comment: I had to move the function outside of the document ready and the variable declaration with it.